# How to manually append to response packet lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I am new to using the lombok library in java. I have a list of items I am trying to append to my response like this:

```
for(Inbox msg:messages) {           
    resp = resp.builder().name(userName).subject(msg.getTitle()).build();
    serverHandle.getLog().info(resp.toString());
}
```

However, this does not append the entries, it just overwrites the existing record. Is there a way to add to the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

assuming this is your `response class` :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Response {
    private String name;
    private String subject;
}
```

Then `lombok` preduce you this `class` :

```
public class Response {
    private String name;
    private String subject;

    Response(String name, String subject) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public static Response.ResponseBuilder builder() {
        return new Response.ResponseBuilder();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return this.subject;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public static class ResponseBuilder {
        private String name;
        private String subject;

        ResponseBuilder() {
        }

        public Response.ResponseBuilder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Response.ResponseBuilder subject(String subject) {
            this.subject = subject;
            return this;
        }

        public Response build() {
            return new Response(this.name, this.subject);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Response.ResponseBuilder(name=" + this.name + ", subject=" + this.subject + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

And as you can see for each `builder` it's creating a new instance of `ResponseBuilder`

```
public static Response.ResponseBuilder builder() {
    return new Response.ResponseBuilder();
}
```